# What is the big data in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, bigdata

Can anyone please explain me in simple words what is big data and how it can be used for the data that is too diverse and fast changing in mongodb... I read the docs but didn't get anything.

Well I am not a newbie in mongodb and have good experience but couldn't able to get the documentation.

Comment: Uhm, they kinda explained it [here](https://www.mongodb.com/big-data-explained)? It's basically about more efficiently dealing with data that's remarkable in terms of volume, velocity, and variety.  Traditional relational database systems could have more trouble with chewing on a few pentabytes of data.

Comment: I read that but did not get it properly... Can you please explain in short and simply way

Comment: Big Data is more like a collective name for a bunch of technologies to get something usefull from a crap load of mostly unstructured data. Like NoSQL, MapReduce, Hadoop.  And MongoDB is a document database aiming to be a good fit in that story.

Comment: @LukStorms As he didn't able to get the docs... Please help him by posting an answer with a brief explaination... Thanks

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet I rather not. I expected this question to be closed by now as off-topic or to broad. But I just added the bigdata tag to it. Perhaps the experts that have that tag bookmarked are interested in giving a concise enlightment on this subject.